# how to write a contract to set a reward for players and they claim the reward?

Tags: solidity, remix

I want to create a contract to give the players rewards and they claim their rewards.

It seems everything is ok!

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Rewards is Ownable {
    IERC20 public rewardsToken;

    mapping(address => uint) public rewards;

    constructor(address _rewardsToken) {
        rewardsToken = IERC20(_rewardsToken);
    }

    function setReward(address account,uint256 amount)  public onlyOwner  {
        rewards[account] = amount;
    }

    function claimReward() public{
        uint256 reward = rewards[msg.sender];
        rewards[msg.sender] = 0;
        rewardsToken.transfer(msg.sender, reward);
    }
}
```

but I don't know why when I claim the reward nothing happens and I have this errors.

[image]

how can I send tokens to my contract?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rewardsToken.transfer(msg.sender, reward);
```

This snippet fails because the `Rewards` contract address doesn't hold sufficient token balance.

Solution: Send at least the `reward` amount of tokens to the `Rewards` contract address, so that the contract can transfer them to the user.

Comment: how can I send tokens to contract?

Comment: @Programmer There are many different ways. Since your question contains a screenshot from MetaMask, [here's an article](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015488931-How-to-send-ETH-and-ERC-20-tokens-from-your-MetaMask-wallet) describing sending tokens using this wallet. The recipient is simply the `Rewards` contract address... Note that the recipient needs to be on the same network as the sender and the token contract.

Comment: Is there any way to automatic send tokens when I set the rewards? should I use 'rewardsToken.transfer(msg.sender, RewardContract);'

Comment: @Programmer Your code sends the tokens automatically - from the contract address to the user invoking the `claimReward()` function. The issue is that the sender doesn't have sufficient token balanace... I'm not sure what other automated way you have in mind. If you want to send the tokens from a different address, you can use the `transferFrom()` function (instead of the regular `transfer()`) allowing you to specify the sender address. But this specified sender needs to `approve()` the `Rewards` address to spend their tokens first. This needs to be performed from the sender address directly.

Answer (score 0):

stakingToken = contract address token
rewardsToken = wallet where you have the tokens

Note: You need approve()  the smart contract address  and amount after created this

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Rewards is Ownable {
    IERC20 public stakingToken;
    IERC20 public rewardsToken;    

    mapping(address => uint) public rewards;

    constructor(address _stakingToken, address _rewardsToken) {
        stakingToken = IERC20(_stakingToken);
        rewardsToken = IERC20(_rewardsToken);
    }

    function setReward(address account,uint256 amount)  public onlyOwner  {
        rewards[account] = amount;
    }

    function claimReward() public{
        uint256 reward = rewards[msg.sender];
        rewards[msg.sender] = 0;
        stakingToken.transferFrom(address(rewardsToken), msg.sender,reward);
    }
}
```